# ¿Como agarro un JSon desde AsynTask en android?

Tags: java, android

Esta es mi función:

```
public class JSONRequest extends AsyncTask <String, Void, JSONObject>{

private JSONCallback activity;

public JSONRequest(JSONCallback activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    JSONObject result = null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
    activity.callBack(jsonObject);
}
```

**¿Qué es lo que me falta?**

Comment: Juan Pablo, de donde tomaste este ejemplo, sería importante saber como inicializas el Asynctask,  por el código que tienes el Asynctask se inicializa similar a : new JSONRequest().execute(tustringJson); o new JSONRequest().execute(urlArchivoJSON); creo que es un poco amplia tu pregunta, agrega más detalles.

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas leer el archivo y convertirlo a *JSON*.

Ejemplo:

```
JSONObject json;
URL url = new URL("url");
HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

InputStream is = conexion.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String linea = "";

while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null){
      sb.append(linea);
}
json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

Este código va dentro de la función `doInBackground`, y lo único que tienes que retornar es el *JSON*.

Answer (score 3):

Juan Pablo, revisando tu código, dentro de `doInBackground()` de tu `Asynctask` recibes un String (seguramente un .json) del cual se obtendrá un `JSONObject` el cual será enviado a `onPostExecute()`:

```
public class JSONRequest extends AsyncTask <String, Void, JSONObject>{

private JSONCallback activity;

public JSONRequest(JSONCallback activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    //Recibe un String en formato .json y obtiene un JSONObject.
    JSONObject result = null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    //Recibe el JSONObject obtenido en doInBackground().
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
    activity.callBack(jsonObject);
}
```

En base a lo anterior nos enfocaremos en el método `doInBackground()`, aquí la pregunta es cual es el objeto JSON que deseas obtener, de antemano necesitas saber el nombre para obtenerlo, por ejemplo supongamos tu JSONObject se llama `"datos"`:

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    //Recibe un String en formato .json y obtiene un JSONObject.
    JSONObject data = params[0].getJSONObject("datos");
    //JSONObject result = null;    
}
```

---

Considero tu pregunta un poco amplia, agrego un ejemplo de lo que necesitas, regularmente un parámetro para inicializar tu Asynctask debe ser la url del archivo Json y a partir de este se obtiene ya sea un `JSONObject` o un `JSONArray`, este es un ejemplo:

```
    class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    String url;
    List<NameValuePair> params;

    public JSONParser(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        this.url = url;
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                Log.e("JSON", json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            }

            // Parsea el string a JSONobject.
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // retorna el objeto JSON.
            return jObj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
        activity.callBack(jsonObject);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza las siguientes variables y dentro de OnCreate

```
private ArrayList<Objeto> Obj;
private Blank_Frangment fragment;

fragment=(Blank_Fra) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

Puedes usar la funcion del JSON directamente desde con el callback donde lo vas a implementar y en el onCreate

```
try {
        Obj = new ArrayList<E>();
        JSONArray arreglo = jo.getJSONArray("result");
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length(); i++){
            JSONObject objecto = arreglo.getJSONObject(i);
            Clase objetito = new Clase(objecto.getString("Nombre"));
            Obj.add(objetito);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
    }

    fragment.AgarraArray(Obj);
```

Y utilizas esta funcion donde tengas el las lista

```
 public void AgarraArray(ArrayList<E> Obj){
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),Obj);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Y recuerda de lo extiende las funciones q tu necesitas utilizar por default para poder modificar

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Blank_Frangment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, JSONCallback

JSONRequest extends AsyncTask <String, Void, JSONObject>

MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas saber lo básico del AsyncTask, esto te ayudara

```
public class JSONRequest extends AsyncTask <String, Void, JSONObject>{

private JSONCallback activity;

public JSONRequest(JSONCallback activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    String json; //Lectura de tu json
    try {
        return new JSONObject(json);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    if(jsonObject) {
        activity.callBack(jsonObject);
    } else {
        activity.callError("El json no se ha podido leer");
    }
}
```

y lo llamas así

```
new JSONRequest(JSONActivity.this).excecute();
```

Para la lectura de tu json ya dependeria de donde lo sacaras, de un archivo o un API que devuelve un json

Te recomendaría que no uses AsyncTask para comunicación con un API o ir por contenido especifico a la red, en Android best practices recomiendan el uso de la libreria llamada [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

Una vez, implementado este codigo para poder crear la conexion dentro de la app es muy importante tener en tu  XML de Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

y donde quieres mandar a llamar el request de la siguiente forma

`request = new JSONRequest(this);
 request.execute("pagina");`

Answer (score 0):

Solo recuérdate que en tu actividad principal lo tienes que mandar a llamar con:

```
nombre_clase clase = new nombre_clase(actividad);
clase.excute("url");
```

Una vez que lo mandas a llamar en una función para que hago el request y tienes que manejar tu JSONobject con la funcion callback.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres agarrar un archivo local desde una carpeta es:

```
try{
        AssetManager manager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        InputStream is = manager.open("archivo.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String currentLine;
        while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            textres.setText(currentLine);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Y aqui como puedes leer un archivo desde tu directorio raw

```
try{
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.saludo);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String currenLines;
        currenLines = br.readLine();
        textraw.setText(currenLines);
        is.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El getView de un adapter es el siguiente:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row,null);
    }

    TextView nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NombreTextView);
    TextView hobby = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hobbyTextView);

    nombre.setText(amigos.get(position).getNombre());
    hobby.setText(amigos.get(position).getHobby());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacer un archivo propiedades

```
private final String FILENAME = "name.xml";

Properties properties;


File file = new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
properties = new Properties();

try{
        if(file.exists()){
            // load values on properties object
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            properties.loadFromXML(fis);
            fis.close();
        } else {
            save();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public void save() throws Exception {
    saveProperties();
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    properties.storeToXML(fos, null);
    fos.close();
}

public void saveProperties(){
    properties.setProperty("usuario", inputtext.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el Adapter falto

ArrayList c;
    Activity activity;

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Clase> c , Activity activity) {
    this.c = c;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```